# MinGW include paths conflict

Tags: c++, mingw, mingw-w64

I'm trying to cross-compile on Linux for Win64 using MinGW-w64. Here's my code

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_generators.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc > 1)
        std::cout << std::atoi(argv[1]) << std::endl;

    std::cout << boost::uuids::random_generator()() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

A simple compile fails with the error

```
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-c++ hello.cpp
hello.cpp:4:31: fatal error: boost/uuid/uuid.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>
                               ^
```

Boost is installed in `/usr/include` which apparently the MinGW compiler doesn't search. If I add that path, then...

```
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-c++ -I/usr/include hello.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:314:0,
             from /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/4.9.1/cstdlib:72,
             from hello.cpp:1:
/usr/include/sys/types.h:109:19: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef __ssize_t ssize_t’
 typedef __ssize_t ssize_t;
                   ^
```

MinGW's `cstdlib` is including `/usr/include/stdlib.h` *instead* of `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stdlib.h`! How do I solve this? I need the `-I` in order to include Boost, but then MinGW includes other headers incorrectly.

Comment: boost must also be cross-compiled, the header in /usr/include are for linux only (best guess)

Comment: Yah, it won't work if you copied the Boost include files from Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use boost headers from /usr/include to cross-compile windows binaries.

You should also cross-compile boost.

See this guide for details about how to cross-compile boost on linux (it's for vle, but the first part is about boost):

http://www.vle-project.org/wiki/Cross_compilation_Win32

Update: Given that the guide is a little bit old, makes sense to link to boost documentation:

http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/tasks/crosscompile.html

Comment: I suppose this goes for all non-standard libraries then? That's gonna be a lot of cross compiling.